# Ubuntu 16.04 -ImportError: No module named 'UbuntuDrivers'

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I was having some problems opening software-properties and it was closing; couldn't even open. I tried to open it on the terminal and I'm getting this error:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gdk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py:40: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gdk, Gtk, Gio, GLib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 54, in <module>
    from UbuntuDrivers import detect
ImportError: No module named 'UbuntuDrivers'
```

What can I do to fix this? Or what did I mess with that I shouldn't have done?

Answer (score 12):

It seems you have mistakenly deleted Python library packages for core Ubuntu Drivers. Try reinstalling `ubuntu-drivers-common` package.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common
```

Comment: Hello, this is a kinda old question and I managed to solve this, I don't even remember what I did, but thanks :)

Comment: how tried a lot of things and this worked, thanks a lot