# apt-get return unmet dependencies on installing everything

Tags: apt, dependencies

i cannot seems to use apt-get. it always return error like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdm3 : Depends: gnome-shell (>= 3.19.92) but it is not going to be installed
 libstdc++-7-dev : Depends: libgcc-7-dev (= 7.3.0-28) but it is not installable
 python-qgis : Depends: python-httplib2 but it is not installable
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python-pip-whl (= 20.1.1-2) but 9.0.1-2.3 is to be installed
               Breaks: python-pip but 9.0.1-2.3 is to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

one of the errors that i encounter. above example is when i try to install python tools. the word "gdm3" is always appear. I'm not savvy in unix system. can anyone help?

EDIT:
this is the result when i try to "sudo apt update"

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

also this when i tried to "sudo apt-get install -reinstall ubuntu-drivers-common" as answered in [Ubuntu 16.04 -ImportError: No module named 'UbuntuDrivers'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842138/ubuntu-16-04-importerror-no-module-named-ubuntudrivers)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-drivers-common
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: it doesn't. it gave me this ''' ERROR:root:Cannot import UbuntuDrivers: No module named 'UbuntuDrivers'''

Comment: also this. for your additional clues. (software-properties-gtk:8814): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:33:47.568: Could not load a pixbuf from icon theme.
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.

Comment: Have you tried the suggested `sudo apt --fix-broken install` command?

Comment: @CharlesGreen that also gave me gdm3 error as this : Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: and now my screen turns black forever after rebooting. since I thought it might help. I'm gonna try with a fresh install tomorrow.

Comment: btw how can you guys stand with Linux?.  imma bout to cry and do my project on windows from now on

Comment: You have some odd version numbers in all this mess - Did you add some non-standard repositories at some point?

Comment: no. not that I knew of. I'm a complete newbie, i just want to learn python3. all i did is just around python3 and pip (python3 install perfectly fine. just then i cannot install anything else)

Comment: Please add output of `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question.

Comment: black screen on reboot. sadly I can't do anything about it